# No me deja hacer el proceso de Migracion de los modelos actuales en Django

Tags: python, django, devops

Es que estoy intentado hacer el proceso de migracion en Django y me sale los erros abajo descritos, que podra ser?, muchas gracias quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Puse imagenes en orden, espero lo entiendan

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: y podriamso ver tu modelo?

Comment: Buenos Dias, gracias por sus comentarios, coloque pantallazos y espero ser mas claro asi, gracias!

Comment: que tal, por lo que se pude ver en la consola tienes un keyerror con "user" ademas de que "AppVehiculo no tiene un "User" model, revisa como tienes tu modelo, quizas te falto un paso